# Why the Chern curvature tensor's coefficients satisfy $\overline{c_{j k \lambda \mu}}=c_{k j \mu \lambda}$?

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

This may be a very simple question In Demailly's Complex analytic and differential geometry Chapter7,$6. Positivity concepts for vector bundles,he says:

Let $E$ be a hermitian holomorphic vector bundle  of rank $r$ over $X$,where $\dim_\mathbb C=n$.Denote by $(e_1,...,e_r)$ an orthonormal frame of $E$ over a coordinate path $\Omega\subset X$ with complex coordinates $(z_1,...,z_n)$,and the Chern curvature tensor

$$i\Theta(E)=i\mkern-9mu \sum_ {\substack{1\leq j,k \leq n,\\1\leq \lambda,\mu\leq r}}{\mkern-12mu c_{j k \lambda \mu}}(x)\,\ dz_j\wedge d\overline z_k\otimes e_\lambda^*\otimes e_\mu,$$**then we have $\;\overline{c_{j k \lambda \mu}}=c_{k j \mu\lambda}$.**

I wonder how we can get this relationship,any references and suggestion are appreciated.Thanks a lot.

Comment: This symmetry results from (a) the fact that the curvature matrix is skew-hermitian and (b) the fact that $\overline{dz_j\wedge d\bar z_k} = -dz_k\wedge d\bar z_j$. That gives you two negatives when you switch *both* pairs $jk$ and $\lambda\mu$ and conjugate.

Comment: Dear @TedShifrin,thanks!I figure it out!